# TypeError when comparing values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, typeerror

I have the following code to filter out some data but some of the values are strings, specifically, they say 'Pending'. So first I filter out the values which say 'Pending', then I set a range (500<=x<=1500).

(In the following code, 'data' is a dataframe with the columns [Company, Normal, CAPEX], CAPEX column has ints, floats and one string which says 'Pending')

```
data = data[(data.CAPEX != 'Pending')]
data = data[(data.CAPEX >= 500) & (data.CAPEX <= 1500)]
```

But then an error pops up:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I would like to know if I can eliminate any string and not just those that say 'Pending'. I have already tried
data = data[(type(data.CAPEX) != str)]
But it didn't work.

Also, I don't know what's up with the TypeError. My list contains numbers and I'm comparing them to another number, there are no strings.

Comment: You could create a sample dataframe with the CAPEX column and a few rows of sample data. As stands it seems like you expect us to do that step when writing answers.

Comment: Depending on how you created the dataframe, pandas may have guessed the data types. If reading a CSV and a column has a mix of integers and "Pending", the column will be string values. If no "Pending", then it'll be of int type. So your first or second comparison will fail depending on which it chose. - so its worth noting how you read this DF.

Answer (score 0):

That error is trying to tell you that you can't compare a string to an integer.
I would create a new dataframe that filters out the 'pending' string

`no_pending_df =  data[(data.CAPEX != 'Pending')]`

Then cast the column as integers:

`no_pending_df["CAPEX"] = pd.to_numeric(no_pending_df["CAPEX"])`

and now you should be able to make legal comparisons doing something like:

`compared_no_pending_df = no_pending_df[(no_pending_df.CAPEX >= 500) & (no_pending_df.CAPEX <= 1500)]`